# Create Shopify product with Variant SKU using API

Tags: shopify

I am trying to create Products on Shopify using the API,
In the CSV upload there is a field `Variant SKU` which sets the (default) product SKU, I can't seem to find the correct way to create a product along with this value?

I tried (python3);

```
import requests
import json
from config import SHOPIFY_URL

payload = {
    'product': {
        'title': 'Hello Product',
        'variants': {
            'option1': 'Primary',
            'sku': 'hello-product'
        }
    }
}

requests.post(
    f'{SHOPIFY_URL}/products.json',
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'},
    data=json.dumps(payload)
)
```

The product get created but the SKU doesn't.

**The TL;DR of my question;**
What to I need to pass to fill the Product CSV Upload file's field **Variant SKU**?

#### Update

Thanks to David Lazar's comments, I realized that I need to use a list of variants.

```
payload = {
    'product': {
        'title': 'Hello Product',
        'variants': [
            {
                'option1': 'Primary',
                'sku': 'hello-product'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This however creates the product with one variant using the passed SKU.
However what I am looking is to create the Porduct with its own SKU, no variations for the product, just a SKU for the product.

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/products/product#create

Comment: I know about that page (That's where I took all the code I did.), What I am asking is how to feed to the CSV field **Variant SKU** via API

Comment: Your problem is two-fold. One you are not even trying to inspect the error message Shopify is giving you. Two, once you figure out how to add a product without SKU, you'll know how to do it with SKU... I suspect you are having problems as you are skipping crucial params like price for example.

Comment: I am getting a `201 Created` response with a blank `sku` in the variants

Comment: Ok, I see that I need to use a **list** of variants
```
payload = {
    'product': {
        'title': 'Hello Product',
        'variants': *[*
            {
                'option1': 'Primary',
                'sku': 'hello-product'
            }
        *]*
    }
}
``` However, it still doesn't replace the **Variant SKU** field from the CSV upload.

Comment: You should maybe look into your inventory setup. A variant only has a SKU at a certain location. So maybe when creating variants, with multi-locations, you are getting a problem because you are not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the option1 field from your single variant it will update the Product SKU.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. The OP seems to be trying to create Product-level SKU. This is not really possible. All Shopify Products require at least one Variant. You can create a Product with a Single Option/Variant and SKU but not a "Product SKU" per se.